# How to disable a touchscreen on Surface pro 3

Tags: dual-boot, touchscreen, surface

Long story short, I dropped my surface and the screen cracked. 
This is causing it to have false touches pretty frequently. I managed to disable it on my windows partition where I'm typing this from. But of the two suggested methods I've found:

1. Either disabling it from xinput
2. Add Option "Ignore" "on" to 10-envdev.conf to the end of the section that said touchscreen

have not been successful.
2 being so not successful that it completely broke my ubuntu distribution

Addition bits of info:
The computer in question is a Surface Pro 3
It *was* running ubuntu 15.10

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Was in the same boat.

1. Run `xinput` to list out the input devices. Your touchscreen should show as one of the "pointers".
2. `xinput disable "NTRG0001:01 1B96:1B05"` (your device ID may differ than mine)
3. Add this to your `~/.bashrc` or such to do automatically upon login

---

**UPDATE:** If you are able to attach an external monitor, using `arandr` to deactivate the tablet's monitor will also disable the pointer device.

Comment: Interesting, I'll need to try that out. It looks like it should work.